# Eclipse CDT hangs / CPU hog for 5 seconds after save

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I save a file in Eclipse CDT, do a build, run the program and go back to editing. Then Eclipse grabs the CPU for some 3 - 5 seconds completely, producing an irritating delay in keyboard latency. after some 2, 3 minutes the same issue shows up.

Eclipse Indigo is running on Debian Squeeze inside of a VirtualBox which may use 6 out of 8 processors of a iCore7 8-hyperthread machine. Interesting enough, on the host OS, I see all 8 hyperthreads busy.

This is getting annoying since after every build it stops me 5 seconds from continuing my work. It looks liek it is connected with the indexer, since turnign off the indexer removes the problem (but then the IDE is a btit useless).

I have ample of memory for eclipse, for the Debian guest and for the Java VM.

Any ideas what I can do?

UPDATE: The problem is now solved. I am running
* A fresh version of Debian
* A fresh version of Eclipse
* Without virtualization, ie. on pure metal
* Booted natively from Debian from an SSD

Do not know what the reason was, but the problem is gone now.

Comment: That's quite a setup you have there.

Comment: I have the same issue...  Very annoying.  My colleague at work switched to netbeans and was happy with it for a while, but then it started hogging as well.  I this it's just C++ which is meant to be coded with emacs or vi :-(